# C# - Can/Should I simplify/alter this code snippet?

Tags: c#, coding-style, goto, simplify

I got the following code in my program:

```
#region Handle

    if(HandleLink(input))
        goto Handled;
    else if(HandlePath(input))
        goto Handled;
    else if(HandleGeneratedLink(input))
        goto Handled;
    else ...
    else
        return; // Break if not handled

#endregion

Handled:
```

Im not very happy with this, because to me it seems like a cheat to use a goto in every second line.
Is there a common way to write such a thing or is this a valid solution?

Comment: You could try to set a boolean to true and only set it to false when the case is not handled. If the boolean is true you can use the goto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
if (!HandleLink(input) && !HandlePath(input) && !HandleGeneratedLink(input)) {
    return;
}
// put the code related to "Handled" here
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this answer the most, because it takes the fewest space and I don't have to split the actions (if/else) around the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if (HandleLink(input) || HandlePath(input) || HandleGeneratedLink(input)) {
    // put the code below the "Handled" label here
} else {
    return;
}
```

Since the `||` evaluates the right operand only if the left operand is false, `HandlePath()` will not be called when `HandleLink()` returns true. It works just like your `if...else if` statement!

Alternatively, you can make a variable called `handled`:

```
var handled = false;
if (HandleLink(input) || HandlePath(input) || HandleGeneratedLink(input)) {
    handled = true;
} else {
    return;
}

if (handled) {
    // move the code below the "Handled" label here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(HandleLink(input) || HandlePath(input) || HandleGeneratedLink(input))
 goto Handled;
else
 return;
```